# what is the reason of getting this kind of Errors "invalid use of non-static data member "

Tags: c++, oop

While I'm coding a **Mutator** for class I have got the following **Errors** :
*error1 : invalid use of non-static data member 'MyGraph'*
*error2 :'MyGraph' is a private member of 'MyGraphBuilder'
mygraphbuilder.h:51:11: note: declared private here*    Can you help me please solve this problem !

```
// Header file
class MyGraphBuilder
{
 private:
  graph_t MyGraph;

// Mutator declared in Header, and Defined in The CPP File
void setGraph(graph_t);

}; // end of class
```

Definition of the function on cpp file

```
//This Part only From CPP File not From Header so I added Scope
void setGraph(graph_tYourGraph){
  MyGraphBuilder::MyGraph = YourGraph;
}
// End of Part from CPP File
```

Comment: You don't need to supply the scope.  Just use `MyGraph = YourGraph;`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The Class, and Mutator Function is Declared in The Header File, While Mutator is defined in The CPP file so I added The Scope.

Comment: please post code the reproduces the error not other errors. There is at least one typo

Comment: If you inserted code from your `.cpp` file into code from your `.hpp` file, then you are not showing us the code that caused the error for you. You would be better off posting two code snippets: the declaration from your header file, and the definitions from your source file. Create a [mcve] on your machine (or with an online compiler), then copy-and-paste the code into your question.

Comment: The function `setGraph()` has no relation to `MyGraphBuilder::setGraph()`.  I think this is just a typo in the implementation file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it should be formatted like this in the cpp file

```
void MyGraphBuilder::setGraph(graph_t YourGraph){
    MyGraph = YourGraph;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so Much, i forgot that  ^_^'